# Not able to connect to Oracle datasource using Spring Batch framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a small project that I’m using to learn Spring Batch. I want to read data from Oracle Database and write to an XML file, but I got an error:

> Error creating bean with name 'step1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jobRepository' while setting bean property 'jobRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository' defined in class path resource [Spring/batch/config/spring-batch-contextOriginal.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSource' of bean class [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean]: Bean property 'dataSource' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

I think I put everything but I think the most important things for this error are: `spring-batch-context.xml` and `spring-datasource.xml`. Am I missing something or is something wrong? Let me know if you need more details. Thank you. (I tried the example without using database and it has worked good.)

**spring-batch-context.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

 <import resource="../jobs/jobPerson.xml"/>
  <import resource="../config/spring-datasource.xml" /> 

   <!--  <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>a PlatformTransactionManager is still required
     -->

    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
       <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
       <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
       <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" /> 
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobLauncher"   class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>


    <!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input records -->
    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="springBatch.ExamResultItemProcessor" />

    <!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
    <bean id="jobListener" class="springBatch.ExamResultJobListener" />

    <!-- Step will need a transaction manager -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

**spring-datasource.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd   
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc    
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

   <!-- Info to connect To Database -->
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@*********:1552/******" />     
      <property name="username" value="*******" />
      <property name="password" value="*******" />
   </bean>

   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />

    <!-- create job-meta tables automatically -->
    <jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource">
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-oracle10g.sql" />
        <jdbc:script location="org/springframework/batch/core/schema-oracle10g.sql" />
    </jdbc:initialize-database>


</beans>
```

**jobPerson.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc">

<!--    <import resource="../config/spring-batch-contextOriginal.xml"/> 
 -->    
     <bean id="itemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"  scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/> 

         <property name="sql" value="SELECT internal_Id,individual_Id FROM Person" />

        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="sb.dbToXml.PersonRowMapper"></bean>
        </property>

    </bean>


    <bean id="itemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemWriter">
       <property name="resource" value="file:xml/persons.xml"/>
       <property name="marshaller"  ref="personMarshaller"/>
       <property name="rootTagName" value="persons"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="personMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
       <property name="classesToBeBound">
          <value>sb.dbToxml.Person </value>
       </property>
    </bean>



     <batch:job id="personJob">
        <batch:step id="step1" >
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter"   commit-interval="10" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
        </batch:listeners> 
    </batch:job>


 </beans>
```

**Main class:**

```
package sb.dbToxml;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainDbToXml
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring/batch/config/spring-batch-context.xml");

    JobLauncher jobLauncher= (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");

    Job job=(Job) context.getBean("personJob");

    try
    {
      JobExecution execution=jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
      System.out.println("Main/try :Job Person  Exit Status "+execution.getStatus());
    }
    catch (JobExecutionException e)
    {
      System.out.println("Main /catch :Job Person  failed");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

}
```

**Person class:**

```
package sb.dbToxml;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessOrder;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorOrder;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="Person")
//@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.UNDEFINED)
public class Person
{
  Long internal_id;
  Long Individual_id;

  @XmlElement(name="int_id")
  public Long getInternal_id()
  {
    return internal_id;
  }
  public void setInternal_id(Long internal_id)
  {
    this.internal_id = internal_id;
  }
  @XmlElement(name="indv_id")
  public Long getIndividual_id()
  {
    return Individual_id;
  }
  public void setIndividual_id(Long individual_id)
  {
    Individual_id = individual_id;
  }


}
```

**PersonRawMapper:**

```
package sb.dbToxml;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

public class PersonRowMapper implements RowMapper <Person>
{

  @Override
  public Person mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException
  {
    Person person=new Person();
    person.setIndividual_id(rs.getLong("individual_id"));
    person.setInternal_id(rs.getLong("internal_id"));
    return person;
  }

}
```

Comment: MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean is in-memory repo. use another

Comment: do you know what I can use please instead of that ?

Comment: Check out [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help on shortening your post a little. Because right now, it seems like there is a wee bit too much code. But maybe I’m wrong and all the code is necessary.

Comment: The exception suggest that the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` doesn't have a `dataSource` property, and looking at its [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean.html) it indeed has no such property. Did you mean to set the property `transactionManager` instead?

Comment: I want to use  database to read some data from a table , so how I can do that , I saw in the example that I should have a datasource . I meant instead of MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean what I can use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean` does not have the properties `dataSource`, `transactionManager` and `databaseType`. You should use the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean` instead of the `MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean`:

So replace this:

```
<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
   <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" /> 
</bean>
```

with this:

```
<!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean" >
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> 
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
   <property name="databaseType" value="oracle" /> 
</bean>
```

and it should work.